# how to send order details to paypal when using woo-commerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any hook that woo-commerce, provide for sending order details like product name and its price like it generates invoice for mail.
I am using standard checkout and want to send order details like product name, quantity and price, sub total and all total.

Any suggestion will me. Thanks in advance.